# How to trigger Pinterest Add To Cart event only when you click on the add to cart button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pinterest

I have installed the Pinterest Tag on my ecommerce site on the Product Detail Page. I need the Pinterest tag to trigger the **add to cart conversion event** ONLY when someone clicks on the **add to cart button** that is on my page.

The tag is currently tracking the add to cart event as soon as the page loads. So its tracking even when there was no click to the button because its just going based off the page loading. I need it to track only when the button has been clicked.

(Note, I am using the Pinterest Tag Helper Chrome extension. That is how I can visually see that the tag records the ATC event when the page loads and not when I click the button)

What would be the proper jQuery to track this only on click if my code is laid out like this below: Note, the part of the code that reads ***<img height="1" width="1"*** is where the trigger is happening for add to cart currently.

```
<!-- Pinterest Tag -->
<script>
    !function (e) {
        if (!window.pintrk) {
            window.pintrk = function () {
                window.pintrk.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
            }; var
                n = window.pintrk; n.queue = [], n.version = "3.0"; var
                    t = document.createElement("script"); t.async = !0, t.src = e; var
                        r = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(t, r)
        }
    }("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js");
    pintrk('load', 'MY_PINTEREST_TAG_ID', { em: '<user_email_address>' });
    pintrk('page');
</script>            

<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=MY_PINTEREST_TAG_ID&event=addtocart&ed[value]=@Model.Price&ed[order_quantity]=1&ed[currency]=USD&noscript=1" />

<!-- end Pinterest Tag -->
```

I have searched on their documentation but it does not show how a real world application would tie into their code to trigger the event on click from a button, it just shows static values. The link below is where I sort of got this code from the section called: **Examples of event data in the IMG tag to copy and paste**

https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/add-event-codes

This is the code for my button:

```
    <button class="add-item button-primary" 
    data-item-id="@Model.id"
    data-item-price="@Model.Price"                                                                                       
    data-item-name="@Model.Title">
    Add To Cart
    </button>
```

Comment: I note that the pinterest code examples have the image wrapped in <noscript> tags, meaning "in case the browser doesn't use javascript, here is an image which sends the data to pinterest".  The image should not be used when javascript is enabled.  There are some samples [here](https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/add-event-codes#section-16176) - which has an Add to Cart example.

Comment: Yeah I read that part as well about the noscript and img not be used when they have javascript enabled, so I instead tried it with a script and not the img but kept getting the same result. The page load tracked the event instead of a click. I took a look at the ATC example you are referring to and I modified it a bit and finally got it to work. I just added a .click() to a function that listens for the button click and then sends the data to Pinterest.  $("#addToCartButton").click(function ()

Comment: Right yes, the example just has some pintrk() call, but calling it inside the onclick of a button is the key, well done for figuring it out.